# Difference between <remove name=”" /> and <action method=”unsetChild”> in layout

Tags: layout, theme, blocks

What is the difference between `<action method=”unsetChild”>` and `<remove name=""/>`?

Both functions are used to remove a block from the layout.

Could someone explain with an example?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`<remove name="" />` operates in the global block scope of `Mage_Core_Model_Layout`. These are collected in [`Mage_Core_Model_Layout::generateXml()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L151) and [used to prevent the block with the specified name from *even being instantiated*](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L170). Also, any child blocks declared for a `<remove />`ed block [will *also not be instantiated*](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L164).

`<action method="" />` a.k.a [`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::unsetChild()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L419) is a block-level method which de-lists the indicated child block (by *alias*, not by *name*) from the parent block instance on which the action is being called. This most often results in the block "disappearing" from the rendered output, even though the block instance is still created. Used in combination with the [`::append()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L729) or [`::insert()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php#L625) methods, it is used to perform a "move".

Comment: Just to add to this, if the block does not have an alias then it will match the name.

Comment: Correct, when no alias is provided, the `alias` for a child is set to its `name`. 

Answer (score 2):

`<remove name="" />` ,When finished with all layouts,  Magento will completely delete the block with indicated name="", regardless of which layout  handle it has been added to. Using this method  it is impossible to remove a block from one location and then add it to another

`<action method="unsetChild">` operates only in the context where it is being used. unsetChild is created for moving existing blocks from one place to another. You need to use this method if you want to remove a specific block from a specific layout handle and then insert it to another position or layout handle.

Comment: Not quite; see my answer for corrections.