# CE1.9.2 - Custom Menu - Replace Layout block

Tags: layout, layout-update, custom-block

I've just written a small custom menu module for a site I'm working on, and need it to replace the current base/default `catalog.topnav`. My module's `config.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magz_MyMenu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magz_MyMenu>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymenu module="mymenu">
                    <file>magz_mymenu.xml</file>
                </mymenu>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        ...
        <blocks>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_topmenu>Magz_MyMenu_Block_Html_Topmenu</html_topmenu>
                </rewrite>
            </page>
        </blocks>
        ...
    </global>
</config>
```

... and my layout update file **magz_mymenu.xml** is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="top.menu">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.topnav</name></action>
            <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="magz/page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Now this currently works and renders as it should on the frontend, but I want to know:

1. Am I doing this correctly?
2. Is there a difference between `action method="unsetChild"` and `remove name=`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing this correctly?

What you're doing is "correct", however if what you want to do is replace the `html_topmenu` block with your own version, you don't need the layout, just the block rewrite in your `config.xml` will do.

That way the standard Magento layout will load the block with the alias `page/html_topmenu` and this alias will resolve to *your* block instead of the default block.

> Is there a difference between `action method="unsetChild"` and `remove name=`?

Yes. Please see [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14597/difference-between-remove-name-and-action-method-unsetchild-in-layout).

Comment: Great, thank you Robbie.  The thing is that I have all of my custom templates contained within a similar folder structure inside of `app/design/frontend/magz/default/template/magz/...`. So I would have to have the block reference the correct template `magz/page/html/topmenu.phtml` instead of `page/html/topmenu.phtml` ... I'm unsure what is best practice here, as my theme inherits `rwd/default`.

Comment: And thank you for the clarification between the 2 block removal methods. I do understand now when to use which :)